# How to use json_decode on PHP

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON string:

```
{"createLead":{"client_id":42891}}
```

Need to parse this string with PHP for getting `client_id` value.
using the following command:

```
$json_result= json_decode('{"createLead":{"client_id":42891}}', true);
```

how do I use the response array for getting `client_id` value?
The following command does not work and return empty string:

```
$client_id = $json_result['createLead']['client_id'];
```

Comment: What is the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) saying? The answer to your question is already there!

Comment: it will also help you to check a `var_dump($json_result)`

Comment: That code should work. What are you doing with `$client_id` after this?

Comment: Can you please share the code here, rather than just this. There can be a possibility that the value of client_id becomes null till the time you echo it

Comment: What version of PHP are you using? you code wroks fine. So is PHP version < 5.2.0

Answer (score -2):

use this code

```
<?php
$json = '{"createLead":{"client_id":42891}}';
$json_result= json_decode($json, true);
echo $json_result['createLead']['client_id'];
?>
Output: 42891
```

Comment: Why? How is this any different from the code the OP posted?

Comment: @Chris, there is no difference,  the above code is just formatted. and it is showing output in PHP 5.2 and greater version.